# Creating n amounts of py.plots

Tags: python, loops, sorting

I am writing code to solve numerical solutions to the Schrodinger Equation. The data values are correct(hopefully!), but I am having issues displaying my results. I would like to have a new py.plot for every 5 or so iterations in the the outer for loop. My current code displays all the data on one py.plot. Which is extremely messy.

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Constants
hbar = 1.055*10**-34 #J*s
me = 9.10938356*10**-31 #kg
L= 5.29177*10**-11  #m   ###Width of well

#Inputs---Currently all Arbitary

stepsize = 0.01     ###Step Size


for n in range(1,5):
  
  E=(((n**2)*(hbar**2))/((2*me)*(L**2)))*(6.242*10**18)
  print(E)
  i = 1
  p1=1
  p2=1
  psi=[]
  for z in np.arange(start=0, stop=1+stepsize, step=stepsize):
    v = z**2
    p3 = ((2-(E-v)*stepsize**2)*p2)-p1
    psi = np.append(psi,p3)
    i = i+1
    #This if state makes it print every 20th iteration.. Easier to read output
    if i < 20:
      p1=p2
      p2=p3
    
    elif i==20:
      i=0
      #print(z,p3)
      p1=p2
      p2=p3
  
  
  plt.plot(np.arange(start=0,stop=1+stepsize,step=stepsize), psi, 'o');
  plt.savefig('Schrodinger Plot')```


#Any help would be greatly appreciated!
#P.S. I am a coding novice so laymen's terms would be greatly appreciated!
````

Comment: The outer loop (`for n`) doesn't even *have* 5 iterations.

Comment: That was a big oversite on my part... I lowered it to 4 just to test the outputs. When the for n loop has 20 iterations it outputs every iteration on the same plot so I could not tell if my data was correct. I would still like it to output a new pyplot for each iteration though.